# how do i solve simultaneous differential equations?

Tags: calculus

how do i calculate a function that meets all these requirements:
                              $$f(0) =0, \quad
                          f'(-4)=-8, \quad
                          f'(0)= -6.$$
have tried to solve but cant seem to find a solution.

Comment: you can assume that $$f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$$

Comment: Do you want any function that has those properties, or are you given more properties, like $f$ being a polynomial?

Comment: There are infinite solutions. If you want a unique solution, you have to put some extra constraints. Try a parabola.

Comment: Title makes you think this question is about a system of differential equations.

Answer (score 2):

The criteria you've given severely under-determine the function at hand. In such contexts, the best approach is to construct the function "locally" and then stich the pieces together.

The line $y_1=-6x$ satisfies both of the requirements at $x=0$ and the line $y_2=2x$ satisfies the requirement that $f'(-4)=-8$. If your function looks like $y_1$ near $0$ and $y_2$ near $-4$, you are done, so all you need to do is stitch those two functions together in some fashion. For example, define

$$
g(x) = \left\{\begin{aligned}
&2x && x \leq -2\\
&10x+16 && -2<x<-1\\
& -6x && x\geq -1
\end{aligned}
\right.$$

This gives a continuous, piece-wise linear function that satisfies all the requirements. If you want your function to be a  polynomial, you can do something similar to fit a quadratic to the requirements by solving $2a(0)+b=-6$ and $2a(-4)+b=-8$.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if we assume:

$$\text{f}\left(x\right)=\text{a}\cdot x^2+\text{b}\cdot x+\text{c}\tag1$$

We get:

- When $x=0$:
  $$\text{f}\left(0\right)=\text{a}\cdot0^2+\text{b}\cdot0+\text{c}=\text{c}=0\tag2$$
- When $x=-4$:
  $$\text{f}\space'\left(-4\right)=2\cdot\text{a}\cdot\left(-4\right)+\text{b}=-8\cdot\text{a}+\text{b}=-8\tag3$$
- When $x=0$:
  $$\text{f}\space'\left(0\right)=2\cdot\text{a}\cdot0+\text{b}=\text{b}=-6\tag4$$

So, for $\text{a}$ we get:

$$-8\cdot\text{a}+\left(-6\right)=-8\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\text{a}=\frac{1}{4}\tag5$$